# Installing nested includes with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have project that I am able to build a static library for using CMake but I am running into issue when trying to install my headers in the way I want.

Here is a very stripped down example of the file structure of my project:

```
.
├── modules
|   ├── util1.cpp
|   ├── util2.cpp
│   ├── module_a
|   |   |── file1.cpp
|   |   └── file2.cpp
│   └── module_b
|       |── file3.cpp
|       └── file4.cpp
└── include
    ├── util1.hpp
    ├── util2.hpp
    ├── module_a
    |   |── file1.hpp
    |   └── file2.hpp
    └── module_b
        |── file3.hpp
        └── file4.hpp
```

The meat of my project is enclosed in a module directory with sub-modules within while the includes follow an identical format. Miscellaneous utility related headers are left floating in the `includes` dir.

Currently I am installing each header file individually as such:

```
set(PROJECT_INCLUDES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/util1.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/util2.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/module_a/file1.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/module_a/file2.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/module_b/file3.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/module_b/file4.hpp
)
```

After installing my library to the necessary paths I am able to include as so:

```
#include <myproj/util1.hpp>
#include <myproj/file1.hpp>
#include <myproj/file3.hpp>
```

But wish to have a scheme more like so :

```
#include <myproj/util1.hpp>
#include <myproj/module_a/file1.hpp>
#include <myproj/module_b/file3.hpp>
```

What is the proper way to accomplish a process like this?

Comment: Can you please clarify one thing for me before I answer this? BY installing you mean the install target, i.e. after you `make install` you then wish to preserve the directory tree structure and use it in another project. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to install all files in a directory, use [`install(DIRECTORY)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#directory):

```
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ # note: tailing slash is important here
    DESTINATION include/myproj # installs files to e.g. <install root>/include/myproj/module_a/file1.hpp
)
```

There's also the possibility to include or exclude certain files using the `FILES_MATCHING` option, if you only want to copy some of the files. (This doesn't work well for including some files with a given extension while excluding others with the same extension though.)

Btw: I strongly recommend moving your headers to make the `#include` paths you want to use for users of the installed lib for build tree too. This way there's the option of using `add_subdirectory` instead of accessing an installed version for a project consuming the lib. Also it makes the project a bit easier to maintain, since you don't have to think about whether you need to use the include path for internal or external use...

Comment: This will install the entire directory, which may not be ideal if the directory (for example) includes private headers or other files that you do not wish to install (binary files for example).

Comment: @MilanŠ. For the other files the solution is trivial: just filter the files based on the extension. If you're mixing private and public headers in the same folder, you've chosen the wrong folder structure for your project anyways: You've basically made it impossible to use the lib in the cmake project building the lib without also getting access to headers no target linking the lib should have access to...

Comment: I'm not disputing that, but as you surely know. Sometimes in the "commercial" world you have no choice, most of the times because a company is unwilling to change existing rules/structures/etc... for whatever (bad) reason they may have. In regards to this I remember all too well the mixing of private/public interfaces and the only difference beeing a `p_` prefix in the filename. Heck even `CMake` kind off allows you to do this bad practice by specifing [PUBLIC_HEADER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I wanted to keep my project neat in its file structure and chose to keep includes in a separate folder which has also proven easy for installation. I tried to mimic what openCV and even googletest do in their installations.

Comment: In the end it's up to you what suits you, but this is in general `bad practice` when it comes to installing headers.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually deal with modules Is to make subdirectories with proper src and include folders with their own `CMakeLists.txt` file and add them into the parent folders with `add_subdirectories` direttive.

I think that your header files, even though in different folders, are being included to the CMake project at the same level.

Comment: So I would need to add a CMakeLists.txt file to both my modules and includes directories? I would like to install the header to /usr/local/lib/myproj and then have the module headers accessible from say myproj/module_a/file1.hpp. Would I want to only create a CMakeLists.txt file in the includes directory?

Comment: I don't think this answer applies to this question. The `.cpp` files and `.hpp` files are in different nodes in the directory tree. This would be bad practice in this case (to use `add_subdirectories`).

Comment: I was indeed suggesting a more widely used project structure to take advantage of CMake modularity features.

Comment: Sometimes you can't restructure it due to management issues and if you read the comment from @aaries you can already see the potential bad practice that stems from your approach (if he doesn't restructure it) because you or someone upvoted the idea that he should create a `CMakeLists.txt` in the include folder that persumably would use the sources from a different tree node (i.e.  `../modules/`).

Comment: I suggested a CMakeLists for any submodule with its own source and include folder. Putting CMakeLists just in include folders is nonsense if the library is not header only.

Comment: I know you did, but look at OPs first comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `add_subdirectories` would make sense if your directory tree would look a bit different. But because you have seperated the header files from the implementation files - it would only lead to bad practice, unless you redo your whole directory tree.

EDIT: The `install(DIRECTORY ...)` shouldn't be used in this case as it was intended for literally installing a whole directory. That means copying all the files from that given directory. An example of such use would be a folder with `.png` files that are needed for icons in your program. Thus (out of experience) I do not recommend it's usage for the installation of headers.

I've found/created and stored two macros that help me quickly solve issues across different `best practices` that I come across.

I assume you wish to install the library(/ies) after you build them and then use them in another project, while preserving the specified structure. I've worked in one company where we couldn't change the folder structure, but they didn't mention anything about the install folder. The source folder resembled the one you posted. Hence after some time I got ahold of this macro and it might be useful for you too (regex might've changed across versions hence it might need some updating):

```
macro(install_directory_headers_macro HEADER_LIST)

foreach(HEADER ${${HEADER_LIST}})
    #This gets 2 matches DIR and HEADER (folder path and header file name)
    string(REGEX MATCH "(.*\/*\\*)[\/\\]" DIR ${HEADER})
    install(FILES ${HEADER} DESTINATION include/${DIR})
endforeach(HEADER)

endmacro(install_directory_headers_macro)
```

What this macro does is to preserve the `SOURCE directory` structure of the include files in the install directory. Normally you would have to type it out yourself, this does it for you.

```
# USE:
# set(PROJ_HEADERS moduleA/moduleA.hpp moduleB/moduleB.hpp)
# install_directory_headers_macro(PROJ_HEADERS)
```

---

### Bonus

Ofcourse I once had a different problem as well **(this is most likely not your case)** where within the same company, they wanted to build the files from source while developing it and didn't understand that they no longer can use system paths in the `#include` directives, unless they do some changes within the `CMake` files. If this is your case then this function solves this for you (so you don't have to move a finger):

```
function(export_headers TARGET HEADER_SOURCE_DIR HEADER_DEST_DIR)

# Put all headers that are in the source directory into EXPORT_HEADERS variable
file(GLOB_RECURSE EXPORT_HEADERS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS 
    RELATIVE "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}" 
    "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h"
)

# For each header that will be exported
foreach(HEADER ${EXPORT_HEADERS})

    # Get the directory portion that needs to be created        
    get_filename_component(HEADER_DIRECTORY "${HEADER}" DIRECTORY)

    # Create the directory  
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER_DIRECTORY}"
    )

    if (MSVC)

        # Make a hard link to the file
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND if not exist "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}" \( mklink /h "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}" "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER}" \) 
        )

    else()

        # Make a symbolic link to the file
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET} POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ln -sf "${HEADER_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER}" "${HEADER_DEST_DIR}/${HEADER}"
        )

    endif()


endforeach(HEADER)

endfunction()
```

And then you can easily...

```
# USE:
# add_library(libA STATIC ${LIBA_SOURCES}
# export_headers(libA ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/libA)
# target_include_directories(libA INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

Comment: Using `install_directory_headers_macro(${PROJ_HEADERS})` your macro tries to read a variable with the name `moduleA/moduleA.hpp;moduleB/moduleB.hpp`; your macro expects the name of a variable to be passed. For a variable number of parameters, but at least 1 you should be specifying only one parameter explicitly and use `ARGN` for the rest: `macro(install_directory_headers_macro HEADER1) foreach(HEADER IN ITEMS ${HEADER1} ${ARGN}) ...`

Comment: Ahh you are correct, the usage has a typo. I meant to pass just the variable name

Comment: Is there any reason you designed this macro in a way that requires passing a variable name? A macro/function receiving values would be useable in cases where you simply list the files as arguments for the macro and you could use multiple variables or a combination of file names and expanded variables too. The only thing your approach seems to be doing is saving 3 chars in a very specific use case...

Comment: Re-usability was the main issue with both the function and macro (I've actually had more than just these here), limited time to produce anything meaningful and I had to work with very old version of CMake. However the main reason is much more nuanced and revolves around poor management and teammates unwilling to learn anything about `CMake`, yet still they wanted to "contribute" to it (and in the result break it, forcing me to fix it), because it was easy to hide them slacking off on `CMake` tasks. In the end I created these so that they use them and not break anything. ...funny...

Comment: This seems overengineering to me for the question asked. Still interesting approach

Comment: The macro that is of interest is 6 lines and saves him typing out individual installs (forever), not all companies/projects follow the same practices - the macro is tailored exactly for his projects needs and doesn't involve restructuring the directory tree that may be bigger than the example provided. How is that over-engineering? The bonus function is just another function that I found in my notes and made me remember the story behind it.